# Core Data slow fetching relationship objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I'm loading all `Node` entities from Core Data with fetch request like this:

```
NSFetchRequest* request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Node"];
self.graphNodes = [self.viewController.objectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

Entity `Node` has one-to-many **ordered** (`NSOrderedSet`) relationship with `Departure` entities. I work with them directly:

```
self.nodeDepartures = node.departures.array;
Departure* departure = self.nodeDeparturesReference[index]; //Slow operation
```

But the last operation executes very slow and I don't understand why. In the XCode's time profiler I see a lot of executes of some `NSSQLCore` methods. Here is an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxzOp.png) of called methods, but the main ones are (in chronological order):

```
[_NSFaultingMutableOrderedSet objectAtIndex:]
[_NSFaultingMutableOrderedSet willReadWithContents:]
[NSFaultHandler retainedFulfillAggregateFaultForObject:andRelationship:withContext:]
[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(_NSInternalMethods) newValueForRelationship:forObjectWithID:withContext:error:]
... and cca. 20 more strange calls (check the image) ...
```

As far as I see, some error is occurred and the program can't find needed data. What am I doing wrong? Any ideas, please.

**EDIT 1:**
I found out that problem was in faulting relationship (more about faulting [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/FaultingandUniquing.html)). The problem was "solved" with new way to fetch nodes:

```
NSFetchRequest* request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Node"];
[request setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
[request setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:@[ @"departures" ]];
self.graphNodes = [self.viewController.objectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

Anyway, it is **not** a good solution for me, because this prefetching takes a lot of time, but I need `Nodes` array immediately. Is there any way to prefetch `departures` property in background thread and use an array in parallel?

Comment: You could try adding `-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1` to 'Arguments passed on launch' in your build scheme - this will cause the console to log the SQL queries Core Data is executing, and might give some insight into what is going wrong

Comment: Out of interest, is it any quicker if the relationship is unordered?  Could you use unordered objects, and then sort in memory?

Comment: Do you have some 'heavy' object in your Departure schemas that can cause a slowdown in fetching time (images, blob > 1 Mo)?

Comment: How many objects are in this ordered relationship, roughly?

Comment: Thank you for response. 
@pbasdf Unfortunately, I need to have this entities sorted.
@FlorianBurel In Departure entity I have 1x `String`, 2x `Integer 16`, 3x `Date` and 4x relationships one-to-one. 
@TomHarrington Totally I have ~1'500'000 Departures (cca. 1`000 per Node).

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track, but with 1000 or so relationships per node you need to go a little farther.

Managed object contexts maintain an internal cache of fetched objects. You probably need to try and "warm up" the cache by fetching the objects in advance, before you need them. Fetch them early but don't use them. Then later when you need them, fetch again and the result will come from the cache.

The initial fetch doesn't need to ask for complete objects. You can set the `resultType` to `managedObjectIDResultType` and get the same result.

This will work best if you're using a background queue, i.e. one that doesn't use the main queue. Before you need the results, tell the background queue to perform this fetch in the background and then don't use the results.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried to do this, but it is too slow anyway. Now I'm trying to use another data structure named `NSData`. I load it on the start of the application like this: `Structure* database = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:my_data];` where `my_data` is data from imported file. Unfortunately, it is even slower than sql method. Do you know any way to load needed data from the file fast? Maybe, can I create something like "memory dump" and load it without unarchiving?

Comment: What I wonder is whether you really need all ~1000 related objects **at the same time** or if you could be using a different approach that didn't get them all at once. One of the main advantages of Core Data is that it's possible to load only a subset of your data instead of all of it.

Comment: I need all related objects because the application depends on user's input data. I don't know user's input before it is typed, but when it is typed, result must be shown as soon as possible.

Comment: I mean, what are you doing with those 1000 objects when you get them? Showing all of them on the screen at once? Doing some kind of calculation based on them? There's probably a better way that doesn't require having all of them in memory at once.